# Does intersection of smooth divisors satisfy Serre $S_2$ criterion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-space

Suppose $X$ is a smooth projective variety, and $H_1,H_2$ are smooth divisors. Does $H_1\cap H_2$ satisfy Serre $S_2$ criterion: for every prime $p$ the local ring $R_p$ has depth at least $\min\{2,\, \dim(R_p)\}$?

How about the special case $X=\mathbb{P^2}_{[X_0,X_1,X_2]}\times\mathbb{P^2}_{[Y_0,Y_1,Y_2]}\times\mathbb{P}^{15}$ (the last space has coordinates $a_{d_0d_1d_2}$ with ${\sum d_i=4}
$, in other words, they parameterize degree $4$ plane curves) and $H_1=\sum a_{d_0d_1d_2}X_0^{d_0}X_1^{d_1}X_2^{d_2}$, $H_2=\sum a_{d_0d_1d_2}Y_0^{d_0}Y_1^{d_1}Y_2^{d_2}$. In this case, the singular locus has codimension at least $2$, I hope it would be normal, but I am not clear how to check the $S_2$ criterion.

Comment: What is $R$ in your case?

Comment: @user26857 I think it runs over the local ring of $H_1\cap H_2$ at some point. I am not sure how to write it down explicitly. I can only think it locally as obtained from the ring $K[X_i,Y_i,a_{d_1d_2d_3}]/(H_1,H_2)$: on affine cover $(X_i\neq 0,Y_j\neq 0,a_{d_1d_2d_3}\neq 0)$, we take $X_i=Y_j=a_{d_1d_2d_3}=1$.

Comment: @user26857 But if there are other ways to show $H_1\cap H_2$ is normal in that case, it would also be great.